# Spamassassin - add every header

Tags: spamassassin, amavis

I am using spamassassin via Amavisd-new.  I have amavisd set to include headers on spam and ham messages via "$sa_tag_level_deflt  = -9999.0;"

2 questions...

a) I want to be sure I am configured to show as much detail as possibl efrom spamassassin in my headers.  I have these 3 lines in my local.cf:

```
add_header all Status "_YESNO_, score=_SCORE_ required=_REQD_ tests=_TESTS_ _RBL_ autolearn=_AUTOLEARN_ version=_VERSION_ "

add_header all Pyzor _PYZOR_

add_header all  DCC _DCCB_: _DCCR_
```

How do I tell if I have everything?  Is this it?  For example I have Razor2 enabled, but I don't know if it has an explicit header setting.  I want to be sure I'm including everything.  Not sure if I'm omitting anything or not.

b) Is there a way to get it to show all tests in the headers, even those with zero scores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, when using amavisd-new, it will drop non-default headers generated by SpamAssassin. To override that, you need to specify which headers amavisd should keep (eg. in `/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user`) like this:

```
$allowed_added_header_fields{lc('X-Spam-Pyzor')} = 1;
$allowed_added_header_fields{lc('X-Spam-DCC')} = 1;
```

Comment: thank you.  Is there a way to figure out what all the SA non-default headers are?  So they can be excluded or not?  If it deletes them before I see them, not sure how to see what would have been there.

Comment: On the server, as the user running spamassassin (usually `amavis`) run the following: `spamassassin -t example_mail.txt | grep '^X-Spam'` (where `example_mail.txt` is any file containing rfc822 e-mail ). That should show all headers (default or extra ones added by `add_header`) that spamassassin is producing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the list here:

http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html#template_tags